# How to decode refresh token? in openiddict

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I am trying

```
services.AddDataProtection()
.SetApplicationName("Testervice")
.ProtectKeysWithCertificate(newCert);
```

but got error

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: was not found in the key ring

Comment: If I had to guess you are trying to load a cert from a file. From what I recall the cert needs to be read from the certificate store or this doesn't work. https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/139#issuecomment-205898117